# Solve the differential equation $\left(y'\right)^3+\left(3x-6\right)\cdot \:y'=3x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This equation, which does not respect the original loosed. Lagrange Equation and Claire.

$$\left(y'\right)^3+\left(3x-6\right)\cdot \:y'=3x$$

I did not want to address here, but I had to, because I can not solve it. Even WolframAlpfa knows incremental solutions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the method in http://www.ae.illinois.edu/lndvl/Publications/2002_IJND.pdf#page=2:

Let $F(x,y,t)=t^3+(3x-6)t-3x$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}}{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}+t\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}}=-\dfrac{3t^2+3x-6}{3t-3}=-\dfrac{x}{t-1}-\dfrac{t^2-2}{t-1}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\dfrac{x}{t-1}=-\dfrac{t^2-2}{t-1}$

I.F.$=e^{\int\frac{1}{t-1}dt}=e^{\ln(t-1)}=t-1$

$\therefore\dfrac{d}{dt}((t-1)x)=2-t^2$

$(t-1)x=\int(2-t^2)~dt$

$(t-1)x=2t-\dfrac{t^3}{3}+C_1$

$x=\dfrac{t(6-t^2)}{3(t-1)}+\dfrac{C_1}{t-1}$

$\therefore\dfrac{dy}{dt}=tx=\dfrac{t^2(6-t^2)}{3(t-1)}+\dfrac{C_1t}{t-1}$

$y=\int\left(\dfrac{t^2(6-t^2)}{3(t-1)}+\dfrac{C_1t}{t-1}\right)dt$

$y=\dfrac{(3C_1+5)\ln(t-1)}{3}+\dfrac{(3C_1+8)(t-1)}{3}-\dfrac{4(t-1)^3}{9}-\dfrac{(t-1)^4}{12}+C_2$

Hence $\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{t(6-t^2)}{3(t-1)}+\dfrac{C_1}{t-1}\\y=\dfrac{(3C_1+5)\ln(t-1)}{3}+\dfrac{(3C_1+8)(t-1)}{3}-\dfrac{4(t-1)^3}{9}-\dfrac{(t-1)^4}{12}+C_2\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

Maple gives the following result (one of three solutions)

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(12x+4\sqrt{4x^3-15x^2+48x-32})^{2/3}-4x+8}{(12x+4\sqrt{4x^3-15x^2+48x-32})^{1/3}}dx+c$$

EDIT:

You can substitute $z=y'$. Then your problem is just a polynomial of third degree. Find its solutions by Cardanos formula. Then integrate the resulting functions. Actually this problem is just a problem of integration.

Comment: But how to solve the equation itself?

Comment: Added a comment.

Comment: Well, I thought so too. Substituting, we get: $z^3+\left(3x-6\right)z=3x$

Comment: And what happened to him to do next?

Comment: You get three functions of x or z1=f(x), z2=g(x) and z3=h(x). now you plug in z1=y1'=f(x), solving this is a simple integration