# Solve the differential equation $y=\frac{3}{2}xy'+e^{y'}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This equation, which does not respect the original loosed. Lagrange Equation and Claire.

$$y=\frac{3}{2}xy'+e^{y'}$$

This is the second equation, which I can not find. Here's the first:
[Solve the differential equation $\left(y'\right)^3+\left(3x-6\right)\cdot \:y'=3x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521371/solve-the-differential-equation-lefty-right3-left3x-6-right-cdot-y-3)

I would be grateful if you help. Since Wolfram even can not help :(

Comment: i would be very generous if you could share your attepts of solving thi proplem :)

Comment: @tired, You also do not know how to solve them? (

Comment: the point is, that on this site it is expected the users show their own attempts to the problem they encountered. And this means a little bit more then just stating "WA can't solve it". As long as you don't respect this, it is very unlikely that you will get nice answers.

Comment: Well, if I only know that there may be (!) It is necessary to make the change: $y'=z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=\dfrac{3}{2}xy'+e^{y'}$

$3xy'+2e^{y'}-2y=0$

Apply the method in http://www.ae.illinois.edu/lndvl/Publications/2002_IJND.pdf#page=2:

Let $F(x,y,t)=3xt+2e^t-2y$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}}{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}+t\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}}=-\dfrac{3x+2e^t}{3t+t(-2)}=-\dfrac{3x}{t}-\dfrac{2e^t}{t}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\dfrac{3x}{t}=-\dfrac{2e^t}{t}$

I.F.$=e^{\int\frac{3}{t}dt}=e^{3\ln t}=t^3$

$\therefore\dfrac{d(t^3x)}{dt}=-2t^2e^t$

$t^3x=-\int2t^2e^t~dt$

$t^3x=-2(t^2-2t+2)e^t+C_1$

$x=\dfrac{C_1}{t^3}-\dfrac{2(t^2-2t+2)e^t}{t^3}$

$\therefore\dfrac{dy}{dt}=tx=\dfrac{C_1}{t^2}-\dfrac{2(t^2-2t+2)e^t}{t^2}$

$y=C_2-\dfrac{C_1}{t}-\int^t\dfrac{2(t^2-2t+2)e^t}{t^2}dt$

Hence $\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{C_1}{t^3}-\dfrac{2(t^2-2t+2)e^t}{t^3}\\y=C_2-\dfrac{C_1}{t}-\int^t\dfrac{2(t^2-2t+2)e^t}{t^2}dt\end{cases}$